# Преобразовать ключ массива в переменную

Tags: ооп, php

Как превратить ключ массива в переменную ($this->$key = $value;)?

```
private $font;
private $width;
private $height;
private $symbols;
private $sesname;

function __construct()
{
    $default = array(
        'font' => 'arial.ttf',
        'width' => 120,
        'height' => 30,
        'symbols' => '1234567890abcfgkpvnsx',
        'sesname' => 'captcha'
    );

    foreach ($default as $key => $value) {
        /* Вот здесь, как сделать? */
        $this->$key = $value;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Так вы же все правильно делаете

Comment: Так разве не проще значения по дефолту сразу переменным класа при объявлении присвоить?

Comment: @Ale_x, зависит от дизайна. Если задуманно потом этот массив вынести в конфиг/параметры, то почему бы не сделать и так?

Answer (score 1):

Можно красиво все сделать через __set()

Answer (score 0):

напишите `$this->{$key}` и будет вам счастье! )

Comment: Оно и без этого будет работать, если нет статической `$key`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($default as $item) {
    $this->$key = reset($item);
}
```

reset - ресетит поинтер в массиве и возвращает значение первого элемента, 
так как в итерации item представляет собой массив из одного элемента, его 
значение и будет возвращено.

Надеюсь правильно понял вопрос

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach ($default as $key => $value)
```

Вот `$value` и есть Ваша переменная. Все правильно сделано.

Comment: Да хорош уже транслитом писать. Есть куча сервисов по переводу.